# XE4/FireDAC uADStanCipher not found error

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, firedac

When I try to compile my XE4/FireDAC project I receive the following error:

```
[dcc32 Fatal Error] uADPhysSQLiteCli.pas(992): F1026 File not found: '<project path>\uADStanCipher.dcu'
```

I have searched for solutions and it seems that the file is not distributed with the standard FireDAC installer due to export restrictions.

Some Google results refer to the link http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/29376. It appears that the link should allow you to download the correct file. Unfortunately I receive an **Unavailable Submission** error.

I am a fully registered user of XE4.

Has anybody found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That CodeCentral item is only for XE3 users. If you have not registered XE3 you don't have access nor would the dcu help you with XE4.

I can't remember to have done something about it, but I can find those dcu's for different platforms in the FireDAC dcu folder.

Comment: Thanks Uwe. Adding C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\FireDAC\Dcu\D18\win32 to the library path 'fixes' the problem. Why would Embarcadero not add this path in the first place if they were not distributing the source file? Do you think it is possible to get hold of the original source file?

Comment: The path IS added during the installation - at least here. Concerning the source, I have no clue. Perhaps when you purchase StreamSec Tools?

Comment: Not here unfortunately. This is a brand new installation of XE4 and FireDAC.

Comment: One hint to get its source. The installer is well known and open source... (that should be enough as hint)