# FireDac installation in XE4 fails

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, firedac, anydac

I have installed Delphi XE 4 Enterprice Update1 on my computer. I tried to install Fire DAC 8.0.5.3365, but during installation got many errors like:

```
Source\uADStanCipher.pas(181) Error: E2010 Incompatible types: 'Byte' and 'Char'

Source\uADStanCipher.pas(941) Error: E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ADMove'
Source\uADStanCipher.pas(1005) Error: E2010 Incompatible types: 'Byte' and 'Char
'
Source\uADStanCipher.pas(1007) Error: E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ADMove'
Source\uADStanCipher.pas(1047) Error: E2010 Incompatible types: 'Byte' and 'Char
'
Source\uADStanCipher.pas(1093) Error: E2010 Incompatible types: 'Byte' and 'Char
'
Source\uADStanCipher.pas(1099) Error: E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ADMove'
Source\uADStanCipher.pas(1143) Error: E2010 Incompatible types: 'Byte' and 'Char
'
Source\uADStanCipher.pas(1228) Error: E2010 Incompatible types: 'Byte' and 'Char
'
Source\uADStanCipher.pas(1243) Error: E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ADMove'
Source\uADStanCipher.pas(1280) Error: E2010 Incompatible types: 'Byte' and 'Char
'
Source\uADStanCipher.pas(1282) Error: E2010 Incompatible types: 'Byte' and 'Char
'
Source\uADStanCipher.pas(1347) Error: E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ADMove'
Source\uADStanCipher.pas(1370) Error: E2010 Incompatible types: 'Byte' and 'Char
'
Source\uADStanCipher.pas(1424) Error: E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'ADMove'
Source\uADStanCipher.pas(1498) Warning: W1000 Symbol 'StrLIComp' is deprecated:
'Moved to the AnsiStrings unit'
Source\uADStanCipher.pas(1536)
Packages\AnyDAC_ComI_D18.dpk(487) Fatal: F2063 Could not compile used unit 'uADS
tanCipher.pas'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

What might be wrong? I have Delphi 2007 installed on my PC also, maybe it conflicts with XE someway

Comment: Is this a clean install of Firedac?  Or an upgrade of an older version?  If it is an update, try installing Firedac in a completely new folder.

Comment: Embarcadero offers free technical support for installation issues. You should contact them via their [Support Page](http://support.embarcadero.com) for help with this type of issue. Also, see [XE4/FireDAC uADStanCipher not found error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771890/xe4-firedac-uadstancipher-not-found-error).